# Knowing the logged in user in Flash TCP Socket server with Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to have a TCP server (by googling since March I could say a "Flash policy server"), to allow Flash games on my Django front-end to communicate with my models on the back-end. I already use consumers.py for WebSocket games (HTML5), but I am unable to find any guidance or resources for Flash games communication in Django.

I am using the following example TCP server (**SocketServer** package with **python 2.7**), and all I need to know is *which Django user is requesting the "policy-file-request"*. In consumers.py (WebSocket) this can be done with **@channel_session_user_from_http**, which is what I am doing right now for the HTML5 games.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import SocketServer

class FlashPolicyHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    timeout = 5

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()

        if self.data == '<policy-file-request/>':
            self.request.sendall('<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" /></cross-domain-policy>')

        self.request.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 9999
    SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), FlashPolicyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```